# How can I handle updating data both in the frontend and backend using an ngrx reducer

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I am building an e-commerce website using Angular and Ngrx for state management. I am having trouble updating data both in the frontend and backend using a reducer.

In my application, I have a product detail page where users can update the product information such as the name, price, and description. When the user clicks the save button, I dispatch an action to update the product information in the store.

I also have a service that makes an API call to update the product information in the backend. However, I am not sure how to handle the update in both the frontend and backend in the reducer.

Here is the code I have tried so far:

```
// product.reducer.ts
import { createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import { updateProduct } from './product.actions';

export const initialState = {
  products: []
};

export const productReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(updateProduct, (state, { product }) => {
    // I am not sure how to handle the update for both frontend and backend here
    return state;
  })
);

// product.service.ts
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  updateProduct(productId: number, productData: any) {
    return this.http.patch(`/api/products/${productId}`, productData);
  }
}
```

Comment: check this out:https://v7.ngrx.io/guide/effects#:~:text=Effects%20are%20long%2Drunning%20services,and%20return%20a%20new%20action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `reducer` is a pure (synchronous) function.
The best practice is to not invoke backend calls in the reducer, instead use `@ngrx/effects`.

The flow then becomes:

Component dispatch Fetch Action => Effect listen to Fetch Action, make the request, and dispatch Fetch Action Success Action => Reducer listen to Success Action, update state.

If you don't want to wait for the success action you can also update the reducer on the Fetch Action, but you still need the effect to make the backend request.